# Eclipse crashes when searching for file

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm running Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) Build id: 20160218-0600 on Ubuntu on Virtualbox.  When I do a file search for files containing text on a selected project, Eclipse crashes.  It doesn't when I search the whole workspace.  I tried creating a new workspace, importing the project again, and running the "eclipse -clean" command.  This is all I see in my eclipse .log file when running "eclipse -debug":

```
!SESSION 2016-06-27 18:41:00.059 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.5.2.M20160212-1500
java.version=1.8.0_91
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2016-06-27 18:41:10.376
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.
```

debug console output:

```
weblogic@weblogic-VirtualBox:/opt/eclipse$ ./eclipse -debug
Start VM: /opt/java/jdk1.7/latest/bin/java
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-Xverify:none
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms256m
-Xmx3072m
-jar /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.5.2.v20160212-1500/splash.bmp
-launcher /opt/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417/eclipse_1612.so
-startup /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 18000c
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-debug
-vm /opt/java/jdk1.7/latest/bin/java
-vmargs
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-Xverify:none
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms256m
-Xmx3072m
-jar /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
Install location:
    file:/opt/eclipse/
Configuration file:
    file:/opt/eclipse/configuration/config.ini loaded
Configuration location:
    file:/opt/eclipse/configuration/
Framework located:
    file:/opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.102.v20160118-1700.jar
Loading extension: reference:file:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.100.v20150402-1551.jar
    eclipse.properties not found
Framework classpath:
    file:/opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.102.v20160118-1700.jar
    file:/opt/eclipse/plugins/
    file:/opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.100.v20150402-1551.jar
Splash location:
    /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.5.2.v20160212-1500/splash.bmp
Debug options:
    file:/opt/eclipse/.options not found
Time to load bundles: 20
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
Starting application: 5580
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: /home/weblogic/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.6.2.20150902-0002.xml
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://914.fwk1319778140:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://914.fwk1319778140:2/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
Application Started: 18641
```

Comment: Very odd to see the references to BOTH JDK 1.7 and JDK 1.8.  Try to remove JDK 1.7 from the equation.  It's probably not causing this particular problem, but it's a variable you don't need.

Comment: It's pretty well known that the default rendering engine of GTK3 isn't working well with Eclipse.  Add the ini flag to turn off GTK3.

Comment: @David M. Karr, I run Eclipse itself with Java 1.8, but execute 1.7 JREs inside of Eclipse since that's what we deploy in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled GTK3 as described in the comment above and have not gotten the error since.

```
In my /etc/profile:
#Gtk3 forced:
#export SWT_GTK3=1
#Gtk2 forced:
export SWT_GTK3=0
```

Comment: Uh, ok.  Did this fix the problem?  That's sort of an important thing to say, if you're providing an "answer".